# Returning multiplied matrix array

Tags: c#, matrix

Is there a more clever way of writing this piece of code? It does work but I thought there might be a better way of returning a matrix from multiplying the parameter by itself.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] m1 = CreateMatrix(5);            
}

static int[,] CreateMatrix(int rowscols)
{            
    int[,] result = new int[rowscols, rowscols];

    int res = rowscols * rowscols;
    int counter= 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowscols; ++i)
    {                                                
        for (int k = 0; k < rowscols; ++k)
        {                    
            result[i, k] = (res - counter);
            counter += 1;
        }                
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`rowscols` is not a very good name.
Although on one hand it's "accurate",
on another it's kind of awkward.
How about `dimension` or `dim` instead?

`res` is also not a very good name.
Since its value is `dim * dim`,
it's the number of cells in the matrix, so `cellCount` would be better.

It would be better to move the `counter` variable inside the loop,
by declaring it in the outer loop together with `i`,
and incrementing it in the innermost loop together with `k`.

It's a common practice to name loop variables `i`, `j`, `k`.
You skipped `j` and went directly for `k`.
It's not a "problem",
but `j` would be more natural,
especially because at school (I think) they teach matrices typically with \$m_{ij}\$ notation rather than \$m_{ik}\$

Lastly,
since the result of the function is a matrix,
it will be more meaningful to call the variable `matrix` instead of `result`.

#### Suggested implementation

Putting the above suggestions together:

```
static int[,] CreateMatrix(int dimension)
{            
    var matrix = new int[dimension, dimension];

    var cellCount = dimension * dimension;

    for (int i = 0, counter = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
    {                                                
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j, ++counter)
        {                    
            matrix[i, j] = cellCount - counter;
        }                
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

*Special thanks to [@Abbas](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22020/abbas) for pointing out to use the `var` keyword instead of explicitly declaring the `matrix` and `cellCount` variables.*

Comment: +1, very nice answer. I'd only like to add two things. 1. Use the `var` keyword instead of explicitly declaring your variables. `dim` is as meaningful as `rowscols`. Ok, a but better but still... I would strongly prefer `dimension`.

Comment: Thanks @Abbas, I agree with your points and updated my answer accordingly.